# How to display inline with svg and text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following snippet :

```css
#reply{
background: lightgray;
}

#inline_txt_svg{
  display: inline-block; 
  max-width: 50px; 
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="reply" class="col-md-12">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
               <div id="inline_txt_svg">
                  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/848/848043.svg">
                  18/06/2020 (15:46)
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore </p>
               <p>et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
               </p>
               <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
               </p>
               <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

I want to the text and the svg be on the same line.

Something like this :

[image]

Comment: `col-xs-offset-X` could be a hint : https://jsfiddle.net/hv90ce18/

Comment: I'll take a look at it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is always a bit fiddling around with the grid to see what fits, I made a little example how I could layout the grid. Hopefully this helps you get around things.

> Note: I changed the col-md tot xs to make it visible within the code-snippet, you can change this back.

```css
#reply {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

#inline_txt_svg {
  display: block;
}

#inline_txt_svg img {
  max-width: 50px;
}

time {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="reply">
    
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
      <div id="inline_txt_svg">
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/848/848043.svg" alt="profile-image">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <time class="">18/06/2020 (15:46)</time>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore </p>
      <p>et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
               </p>
               <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```